# Create a bot that just visits my website

Tags: bots

I have a Wordpress website automatically that gets some information from a RSS feed, posts it and then, with the help of a built-in Wordpress function, sets a custom field for that post with a name and a value. The problem is that this custom field only gets set when someone visits the published post. So, I have to visit every single new post for the custom field to be applied or to wait a visitor to do so.

I was looking forward to create a bot, web-crawler or spider that just visits all my new webpages once in an hour or whatever so the custom field gets automatically applied when the post is published.

There is any way of creating this with PHP, or other web-based language. I'm on a Mac, so I don't think that Visual Basic is a solution but I could try installing it.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to avoid the need for a visit. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I just need a robot to visit my webpage, to run it for the first time so the Wordpress function gets working. The page has to be printed or executed for the function to work. Am I clear enough?

Comment: Why do you need to trigger this via a website visit? It sounds like it would be better just to get the code to run on a schedule defined on the server itself?

Comment: Yes of course. You mean by running some code and have it scheduled with a cronjob inside the server where I have Wordpress installed. That would be great because it will run online. What do you mean?

Answer (score 11):

You could for instance write a shell script that invokes [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (or if you don't have it, you can call `curl -0` instead) and have it scheduled to run every hour, e.g. using `cron`.

It can be as simple as the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -0 mysite.com
```

Assuming it's called `visitor.sh` and is set to be executable, you can then edit your crontab by typing `crontab -e` to schedule it. [Here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714) is a link that explains how to do that second part. You will essentially need to add this line to your crontab:

```
0    *    *    *    *    /path/to/.../visitor.sh
```

(It means: run the script located at `/path/to/.../visitor.sh` every round hour.)

Note that the script would run from your computer, so it will only run when the computer is running.

Comment: you should probably mention cron (as a way to have the script scheduled). +1 anyways.

Comment: Is there anything more easy like doing something in PHP?

Comment: @user1116921: cURL is not limited to PHP. There's also a command line version of cURL. wget is simpler for this purpose, tho, unless you need authentication and other non-trivial stuff.

Comment: Apparently `wget` is not installed by default with Mac OS X. I updated the answer to include `curl`.

Comment: Put it in a new file, called, e.g. `myscript.sh`. Make sure that file can be executable, and that's it, you just wrote a shell script. Simple as that.

Comment: I should call it visitor.sh right? And in my cPanel cron job configuration I put the time 1 hour and then in the code I write crontab -e? I mean I will have to type the place where the visitor.sh is like website.com/visitor.sh?

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw that edit from you. Is there any way of running it online?

Comment: I will have to activate the Apache servers which comes installed in Mac OSX, then install cURL library. After that I set up a cronjob in my cpanel hosted online? Or do I have to do another thing in my localhost? In the case of the online one, the path will be: myip/visitor.sh?

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` is a good point, also you can use `curl` or `lynx` to browse the web. They are pretty light-weighted.

Comment: curl returns text html, which is asked from the service end processes. It depends how your webpage consider a 'visit', say, unique IP address or just hit...

Comment: Anyway I just need someone or a bot to just run or execute every webpage in my site once in an hour. Without necessarily returning something.